# how to update child array and parent element both at the same time using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Look at my following example schema.

```
const ParentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id:String
    name:String
    age:Number
    child:[{
        id:String,
        name:String,
        age:Number}]
    })

const collectionName = mongoose.model("parent", ParentSchema)
```

Now I want to increase the age of child and parent for the specific id of each of them. both at the same time. I tried doing it with the following query

```
collectionName.update({'_id':new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59198a3e73ae303f97e97e8f"),'child._id':new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59198a3e73ae303f97e97eds")},
{$inc:{'age':1},$inc:{'child.$.age':1}},function(err,res){
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }else{
console.log(res)
}
```

Above query worked well but it only updated the child age and not the parent one. Now I'm not sure how should I mould my query to update both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query work for me:

```
db.collection.update({
    '_id': new mongoose.Types.ObjectId("59198a3e73ae303f97e97e8f"), 
    'child.id': A SPECIFIC ID 
}, 
{ 
    $inc: { 'age': 1, 'child.$.age': 1 }
});
```

Your query doesn't work because the $ operator need a condition to verify before increase the appropriate child from the nested array. If you want to go deepen, here is the [official documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/).

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Gianmarco. Actually, it is my bad that I had written the incorrect query in question. But in my real program, I had written the correct version of the query as you have mentioned. And it didn't work. Query you mentioned actully updates the child.age for that specific child.id's condition but it did'nt update the age of parent object

Comment: I have tested this query in mongo shell and it works. In my case the query didn't use the id but it used this condition: { 'name': "mark", 'child.name': "mark's son" } . Now i don't know if the condition type can change the result, but if you want, you can try it to verify.

Comment: yes right @Gianmarco. You were right and your version of query indeed worked even for me after testing it on my code. So basically I was wrong in implementing two $inc sets. And that was where it was wrong. When I updated my version of the query with two increments in single $inc set, it actully did work. Thanks for your time

Comment: @PointNetworks Perfect! No problem, i am glad to help.